# Ext.form.Basic how to reset fields when trackResetOnLoad true?

Tags: forms, extjs, extjs4

I got a `Ext.form.Basic` with the [`trackResetOnLoad`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-cfg-trackResetOnLoad)`:true` config.

When I call `reset()` on a field it gets its values from the form `setValues()` method.
*How do I reset my fields now?*
When I just do `field.setValue('')` the form marks it as invalid because the field is required.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to manually reset all of the `originValues` of all fields (and some other)

This snipped will do this

```
var items = form.getForm().getFields().items,
    i = 0,
    len = items.length;
for(; i < len; i++) {
    var c = items[i];
    c.value = '';
    if(c.mixins && c.mixins.field && typeof c.mixins.field['initValue'] == 'function'){
        c.mixins.field.initValue.apply(c);
        c.wasDirty = false;
    }
}
```

**[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/sZR8M/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is to take a copy of the values just after the form is created using something like `var originalValues = myForm.getFieldValues();` then I can later restore those values using `myForm.setValues(originalValues);` instead of calling `myForm.reset(...);`